# Call var from another function

Tags: jquery

I need to call the id value from another function
Here the code

```
$("p").hover(function() {
    var i = $(this).text();
    $("#o").show();
}, function() {
    $("#o").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
});
$("#o").click(function() {
    $(".display").append(i);
});​
```

I need "i" value display on ".display" class div.
Any one can help me please..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply declare `i` outside..

```
var i = '';
$("p").hover(function() {
   i = $(this).text();
   $("#o").show();
}, 
function() {
   $("#o").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
});

$("#o").click(function() {
   $(".display").append(i);
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sselvamani22/9vg8u/3/
here i need to display the text after the pare on which para i hover... can u help me

Comment: I would definitely suggest wrapping the code in an anonymous function to contain your variables. See the answer below

Answer (score 1):

To add to Vega's answer, I would wrap it in an anonymous function to avoid polluting the global scope.

```
(function() {
    var i = '';
    $("p").hover(function() {
        i = $(this).text();
        $("#o").show();
    }, function() {
        $("#o").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
    });
    $("#o").click(function() {
        $(".display").append(i);
    });​

})();
```

The variable is still accessible to the inner callback functions after the outer function has returned, because javascript has a nice thing called [closures](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/).

Answer (score 1):

Create a closure instead of a global variable...

```
(function (i) {

    $("p").hover(function() {
       i = $(this).text();
        $("#o").show();
    }, function() {
        $("#o").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
    });

    $("#o").click(function() {
        $(".display").append(i);
    });​

}(""));
```

Comment: You are missing a `)`. `}("");` -> `})("")`;

Answer (score 0):

Just use variable scope to your advantage by moving i outside of the functions.

```
var i;
$("p").hover(function() {
    i = $(this).text();
    $("#o").show();
}, function() {
    $("#o").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
});
$("#o").click(function() {
    $(".display").append(i);
});
```